# load messages on scroll in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, message

I am developing a conversations page, where i need to load messages, I am in the stage of pulling record from backend, the ajax call will be send after certain scroll height, I need to query records, like pagination

```
scope :filter_message ->(id) { where('id < ?', id ) if id }

@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id]).messages.filter_message.group_by{ |message| message.created_at.strftime("%M/%D%Y") }
```

I need to filter records based on id with certain limit like 20, on the next scroll load next 20 messages, Any help how to proceed this

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is having an ajax call which calls a controller endpoint passing it and id when the users scrolls to the end of the page. This id should be the first id from where you start count the 20 messages.

So lets say you at the first time when the page is loaded you have 20 messages shown like this:

```
# messages/index.html.erb
<div id="messages" data-url="<%= twenty_more_path %>">
    <% messages.forEach do |message| do %>
        <div class="messages_ids" value="<%= message.id %>"></div>
        ... other stuff ...
    <% end %>
</div>
```

when the user scrolls to the end you make an ajax call like this in a coffeescript file:

```
# assets/javascripts/messages.coffee
# call that method when user scrolls and reaches the end of the list
@fetchMessages = () ->
    after = $('.messages_ids')[$('.messages_ids').length-1].value
    $.get($('#messages').data('url'), after: after)
```

This will trigger a `MessagesController#twenty_more` action:

```
# controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def twenty_more
        @twenty_messages = Message.where("id > ?", params[:after]).limit(20)
    end
end
```

And when the controller action execution ends, a javascript view called `twenty_more.js.erb` will be triggered. This view is responsible for adding those new 20 messages in the `<div id="messages">`

```
# views/messages/twenty_more.js.erb
$('document').ready(function() {
    <% unless @twenty_messages.empty? %>
        $('#messages').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'messages/messages_list') %>");
    <% end %>
});
```

In this `js` view we render a partial called `messages/messages_list` and append it in the `<div id="messages">`.
This partial is written like this:

```
# views/messages/_messages_list
<% @twenty_messages.each do |message| %>
    <div class="messages_ids" value="<%= message.id %>"></div>
    ... other stuff ...
<% end %>
```

You can see that the only thing that we do in the partial is looping through the new messages and print the divs we want.

Note that my code is not tested. Its just a snippet in order to give you an idea about how to proceed.